Type hinting for R, similar to those in Python or Typescript
I'm new to R. I've tried to find variables' type annotations or hinting, similar to type hinting in Python or TypeScript for JavaScript, but I couldn't find anything.
Our AI friends provided me with answers that include type hinting, which can be used by Linters, but it doesn't work, and I couldn't find any information about it.
Am I missing something, or do these really not exist, and the AI is making things up?
Thanks

Does this answer your question? R programming: Is it possible to declare return or parameter types of functions? - similar question but that library looks abandoned. I'm not aware of any newer options.

The R language itself doesn't currently support strong typing. There have maybe been a handful of boutique packages that tried to add support for something like that, but nothing has really gone mainstream for that. It sounds like your AI is hallucinating.

Thank you, so I suppose the answers I received from the AIs are from the past and are no longer valid.

One of the adopted practices in R is to use variable checking provided by the package checkmate. This is usually done at the top of the function body.
Checkers like assert_double or assert_flag (etc.) serve as type hints and can be referenced in the function arguments documentation.
This helps to ensure that the function is being used correctly and that the arguments passed to it are of the expected type.
